# One element multiple times

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to be able to specify one element, in my case `Param`, multiple times.
This is the XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Abc">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Def" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:all>
                            <!-- ... other elements ... -->
                            <xs:element name="Param" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> <!-- Using unbounded is not allowed here -->
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="Name"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="Value"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <!-- ... other elements ... -->
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This is the corresponding XML:

```
<Abc xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SourcesSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Def>
        <Param Name="one" Value="blue"/>
        <Param Name="two" Value="yellow"/>
        <Param Name="three" Value="green"/>
    </Def >
</Abc>
```

Trying this, I get the following exception:

```
Cos-all-limited.2: The {max Occurs} Of An Element In An 'all' Model Group Must Be 0 Or 1. The Value '-1' For Element 'Param' Is Invalid.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xsd:all only allows 0 or 1 occurrence of any of it children.

You could use an xsd::sequence instead.. but know that in that case any element in they are defined in the order in which they must appear in the xml.